# Regex in AzureDevOps web test

Tags: regex, performance-testing, azure-devops

I am testing a scenario in AzureDevOps web performance test. i need to extract all IDs from a response of one page. As there are multiple IDs and extraction pattern is the same. How can I get all IDs in one variable?

following if the page response

```
[ {"Id":20006,"Period":"13-Jul","Territory":"Chicagoelected":true, 
  "Link":"/PSR03/0026-03-a/Web/api/Document/Index/20006",
  "Username":user1,"Viewer":"user1"},
  {"Id":6,"Period":"July2013","Territory":"ChicagoI:false,
  "Link":"/PSR03/0026-03-a/Web/api/Document/Index/6",
  "Username":"user1","Viewer":"user1"},
  {Id:25008,"Period":"13-Jun","Territory":"California",
   "Selected":false,
   "Link":"/PSR03/0026-03-a/Web/api/Document/Index/25008",
   "Username":"user1","Viewer":"user1},
  {Id":25007,"Period":"13-Jun","Territory":"EV,Selected":false,
   "Link":"/PSR03/0026-03-a/Web/api/Document/Index/25007",
   "Username":"user1","Viewer":"user1"},
  {Id:25010,"Period":"13-May","Territory":"California","Selected":false,
  "Link":"/PSR03/0026-03-a/Web/api/Document/Index/25010",
  "Username":"user1","Viewer":"user1},
  {Id":25009,"Period":"13-May","Territory":"Chicago","Selected:false,
   Link":"/PSR03/0026-03-a/Web/api/Document/Index/25009",
  "Username":"user1,Viewer":"user1"},
  {"Id":25005,Period:"13-Mar,Territory":"Chicago","Selected":false,
  "Link":/PSR03/0026-03-a/Web/api/Document/Index/25005", 
  Username:"user1","Viewer":"user1"},
  {"Id":25006,"Period":"13-Mar","Territory":"EV","Selected":false,
   "Link":"/PSR03/0026-03-a/Web/api/Document/Index/25006",
   "Username":"user1","Viewer":"user1"},
  {"Id":25011,"Period":"13-Feb","Territory":"Chicagoelected":false,
   "Link":"/PSR03/0026-03-a/Web/api/Document/Index/25011",
   "Username":"user1","Viewer:user1"}],
   "LocalizationDictionary":
```

---

I am writing regex as - "*Id"*:([0-9]*),"*Period"*
it is working and giving me all IDs in Rubular.
But how can i implement it in VSTS web performance test?

Comment: Have you copied the string properly? There is some mistakes. Some missing double quotes.

Comment: The response text is correctly copied. there is actually a discrepancy in double qoutes.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression extraction rule might get one ID from the data or it might get the entire response. I am not aware of any way with the built in extraction rules to get the data as you need.

I would write a `WebTestRequestPlugin` where the `PostRequest` method extracts and formats the required data.  The plugin itself should access the response body from `e.Response.BodyString`.

The method of extracting the required data and formatting it into one variable depends on the exact data format and that will be complicated because of the information written in a comment by the questioner, namely *"The response text is correctly copied. there is actually a discrepancy in double quotes*". It may be that none of the library routines that might normally be used to parse this sort of data will work due to the missing double quotes.

An outline of the plugin method might be:

```
public override void PostRequest(object sender, PostRequestEventArgs e)
{
    string[] body= e.Response.BodyString;
    string extractedIds = ...; // Extract and format the IDs from body.
    e.WebTest.Context["TheContextParameter"] = extractedIds;
}
```

[This Microsoft page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514192%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gives details on how to write a plugin.

Comment: I completed the part by writing c# code instead of plugin as i found it easier. i directly extracted IDs from response body instead of using a extraction plugin and it worked for me.

Comment: @Rohan.Chitnis Can you clarify what you meant by "*writing c# code instead*". The plugin is also C# code.